# Eclipse Subclipse :Error Validation Location

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have installed subclipse plug in and when tried to check out project following error is shown.I have tried many solution (like Eclipse > Preferences > Team > SVN Under "SVN interface", choose client as "SVNKit(Pure Java) SVNKit v..xx".) but no one is worked for me.
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
svn: OPTIONS of '...svn path': 502 Proxy Error ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  ) (http://address)
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn path'
```

Comment: Read the error carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the proxy error.  If you use a proxy server, it sounds like it does not like the URL and rejected it.  Maybe you are supposed to bypass the proxy for this URL and need to configure the bypass rules in Eclipse proxy settings?

It is not a Subversion error.  Subversion is just relaying back the error it received when it tried to reach the URL you entered.